# Positive Theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

In different model theory textbooks and also in general mathematical  logic textbook books I’ve seen that there are several theorems about the notion of **positive Robinson theory**. But I’ve never been able to find the **exact** definition of Robinson theory and also positive Robinson theory. Can someone give me the exact definition of this odd notion?

Comment: There is a notion of Robinson theory by Hrushovski defined in preprint "Simplicity and the Lascar Group" (it is not published, but you can google for it). Ben-Yaacov generalised it to positive model theory (see e.g. his paper "Compactness and Independence in Non First Order Frameworks"). I am not sure these are the notions that you are looking for. They are used in research, but haven't yet made their way into model theory textbook and more so in general logic textbook. As usual with research, notions evolve and there is no **exact** definition that everyone follows.

Comment: I'm also curious what textbooks you have in mind. I know that Baldwin's *Categoricity* mentions the notion of positive Robinson theory, but that's far from a general mathematical logic book!

Comment: @Alex I heard about this notions in a logic seminar. I also saw a German old  textbook on logic which had a chapter about model theory and in that chapter the author mentioned this notion.

Comment: @Levon Thank you Levon for the reference. I found the definition in Hrushovski’s note. But it was so difficult to understand for me!